# The necessary and sufficient condition of "Linear Map $M_{\phi}$ has an eigenvector."

Tags: real-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I've been struggling with this problem. :
For the function $\phi \in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$, Define $M_{\phi}(f) = \phi f $, $f \in L^2(X,\mu)$ The measure is $\sigma$-finite.

Then, What is the necessary and sufficient condition of "Linear map $M_{\phi}$ has an eigenvector, that is, for some constant $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, the equality $M_{\phi}(f) = \lambda f$ holds.

I guess that there is some similarity between the eigenvector of matrix and the eigenvector of map. It was easy to get an idea when the map is from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$, but how about in some function to function? Could someone give me a hint or any ideas?

Comment: By algebraic manipulatation you get that if $\lambda$ is an Eugenvalue, $\phi = \lambda$ in the support of its eugenvector, this can only happen if $\phi$ is constant in a set of positive measure.

Comment: @FZan Could you please explain me more obviously? I've never studied "Algebraic manipulation" and this problem is from Korean textbook of real analysis. Moreover, I can't understand why the condition "Measure is $\sigma$-finite" is given.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$ so that $\phi f=\lambda f$. On $f$ support we can divide by $f$, so $\phi(x)=\lambda$ for all $x\in sup(f)$. Because $f\neq 0$ then $\mu(sup(f))>0$, so a necessary condition for having eigenvalues is that $\phi$ must be constant in set of positive measure.

Comment: If the measure is $\sigma-$ finite this condition is sufficient. Pick $E=\{ x : \phi(x)=\lambda\}$ so that $\mu(E)>0$. Because $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite there is a set $E'\subseteq E$ so that $0<\mu(E')<+\infty$. The function $\chi_{E'}$ (the characteristic function of $E'$) is not $0$ and in $L^2$. Moreover $\phi\chi_{E'}=\lambda \chi_{E'}$

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks for your help!